# Configure https

Tags: apache, tomcat

I am very new to tomcat. I have an apache tomcat web server [Server version: Apache Tomcat/6.0.28]

I also have a DNS record Name for this web server.

While doing some testing, I tried using an Invalid DNS Name expecting that it would return an error since the DNS name is invalid but this web server just ignore it and no errors were returned.

Is there a way to configure the web server in such a way that it pays attention to the DNS name instead of just ignoring it.

Comment: If it's just ignoring it, it's doing what it is supposed to (I think) -- if the DNS name is wrong it would follow that Tomcat would never even get the request, it would not see it.

Comment: Here I am specifying the IP address of the server as well the DNS name. So if they both don't match it should have given an error. But it seems like tomcat is just checking the IP address and ignoring the DNS name.

Comment: What does Tomcat do if they both don't match?  Does it give any indication that it processes the request or does it act like it got no request at all?  The latter should be the case.

Comment: Yes you are right. Actually in the server.xml file the Host name was set to localhost by default, so no matter whatever my domain name was (valid or invalid) it was getting ignored. However I got it working now....In the ..conf/server.xml file, I just changed the Host name to point to the valid domain name instead of localhost and then restarted tomcat. So now when I enter invalid domain name, in my testing I do see that there is an indication that they are not matching.

Comment: Thank you for your help and quick reply!!!..Appreciate that